# .py файл скомпилированный в .exe при открытии сразу закрывается

Tags: python, python-3.x

Скомпилировала .py файл в .exe через pip, все скомпилировалось без ошибок, но при открытии файла консоль открывается и сразу же закрывается. Советовали в конце написать input(), но это не помогло. Сама программа в .py формате работает исправно.
Вот код:

```
import time
import os
import winreg

# Добавить в автозагрузку 
key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
winreg.SetValueEx(key, "Cheat", 0, winreg.REG_SZ,"%USERPROFILE%\\Programs\\Cheat\\cheat.exe")
key.Close()

# Удалить из авто загрузки
# key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
# winreg.DeleteValue(key, "Date Time")
# key.Close()

while True:
    os.startfile(r'r.png')
    time.sleep(4)
input()
```

Comment: запусти с консольки и просмотри ошибку

Comment: @eri С какой еще консольки? Извиняюсь за тупость, просто я начинающий программист и еще многого не знаю...

Comment: Cmd или bash, там запускать путь к питону путь к файлу

Comment: @eri Запустила, ничего не выдало, программа запустилась исправно.

Comment: Значит оно просто не экзе)

Comment: Вы файл (r.png) добавили в проект? Для проверки просто положите его в папку с EXE. У вас хоть и закроется консоль но но файл изображение должен открыться в другой программе по умолчанию для показа изображений.

Comment: @Александр Блин, я почему-то совсем забыла про тот факт, что картинка должна лежать рядом с .exe'шником. Спасибо, реально помогло!

Comment: Ещё можно изображение добавить в EXE вот ссылка как это сделать https://toster.ru/q/473134

Comment: Ну или укажите полный путь к изображению

Answer (score 1):

Pip не компилятор и даже не сборщик exe приложений. Это менеджер пакетов. Похоже вы не правильно собрали программу.

Попробуйте по инструкциям строго. Например pyinstaller

Comment: извиняюсь, не правильно выразилась. Компилировала через pyinstaller. А точнее командой pyinstaller -F -i "здесь был путь к иконке" cheat.py

Comment: @WaLLian При конвертации файла в .exe может произойти много разных ошибок, даже если исходная программа правильная. У вас видимо какая-то произошла. Короче вам нужно узнать что это за ошибка.  К сожалению я не знаю нормального способа посмотреть ошибку в быстро закрывающемся окне, можете попробовать погуглить. Либо можно тупо сделать скрин ошибки) мне один раз помогло